# Websocket compatibility issues

Tags: c#, websocket

I am using the plain C# `await httpListenerContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync(subProtocol: null)`, everything seems to work great and data is being sent and transmitted from Chrome successfully, however sometimes the connection seems to get dropped for no reason or the client will send the data partially, this is especially annoying since the data is JSON and I will only get half the object (and I am certain I send it full on the client)

I am testing on localhost so any connection issues aren't a possibility (not that they would be anyway because of TCP)

I see that I sometimes receive the following exception:

```
Error while processing account:The 'System.Net.Web
Sockets.ServerWebSocket' instance cannot be used for communication because it ha
s been transitioned into the 'Aborted' state.:System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketExc
eption (0x80004005): The 'System.Net.WebSockets.ServerWebSocket' instance cannot
 be used for communication because it has been transitioned into the 'Aborted' s
tate. ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<ReadAsyncCore>d__
```

Comment: Maybe check the server's error logs?  Run the app in debug?  Watch the actual raw data with Wireshark?  It would help if you show the entire code for the issue.

Comment: The WebSocket protocol does not permit partial messages, so something is seriously wrong (unless you're using a streaming API). Capture the network activity using Chrome dev tools / Fiddler to ensure your client is working as expected.